# Embed google Navigation into a Layout

Tags: android, android-maps

I want to show google navigation in my application as a view in my layout. (Like mapview)
Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: No. It's against google's TOS.

Comment: oh! I would like to read that bit, source?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the following tutorials as a starting point:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/android_v3.html

http://android10.org/index.php/articleslocationmaps/253-how-to-use-google-maps-in-android

I am working on embedding Google Maps/Nav into an app of mine.

Comment: These two links seem to just talk about Google Maps, and don't show how to embed google navigation.  Have I missed something?